# Is every subproduct of rational product is rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, products

Assume we have a 
$$\prod_{p \in P}a_p=R$$ where R is rational.
Is it possible to have a $P_1\subset P$ for which:
$$\prod_{p \in P_1}a_p=I$$ where I is not rational.

ADDITION 1:
where $a_p$ is rational.

ADDITION 2:
and what if $0<a_p<1$

Comment: Yes. Consider
$$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: Please see the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is still yes. Consider
$$\zeta(2) = \prod_{p \textrm{ prime}}\frac{1}{1 - p^{-2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$
Then $\tfrac{\pi^2}{6}$ is a subproduct of
$$\prod_{p \textrm{ prime}}\frac{1}{1 - p^{-2}}\prod_{p \textrm{ prime}}(1 - p^{-2}) = 1.$$

For an example with $0 < a_p < 1$, consider

$$\frac{2}{1}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{3}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{5}\cdot\frac{6}{7}\cdot\frac{8}{7}\cdot\frac{8}{9}\cdot\frac{10}{9} = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Dividing by $2$, grouping consecutive pairs of terms together and squaring gives
$$\frac{8^2}{9^2} \cdot \frac{24^2}{25^2} \cdot \frac{48^2}{49^2} \cdot \frac{80^2}{81^2} \cdots \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((2n + 1)^2 - 1)^2}{(2n + 1)^4} = \frac{\pi^2}{16}.$$
So then
$$\prod_{p \textrm{ prime}}(1 - p^{-2})\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{((2n + 1)^2 - 1)^2}{(2n + 1)^4} = \prod_{p \in P}a_p = \frac{3}{8}$$
is rational and $0 < a_p < 1$ but there are two obvious irrational subproducts.

Comment: Good answer, and please take a look at the last correction.

Comment: Sorry edeited again.

Comment: Just wondering if there is still simple counterexample if $0<a_p<1$.

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan see my edit.

Comment: Great! Just a thought can we have 2 different transcendental subproducts?

Comment: From the logic of your answer I assume the answer is yes.